# Sceencast in C#?

Tags: c#, screenshot, gdi+

I am working on a screencasting program for the Windows platform and can't more than 14fps in 1080p using C# & GDI+ to take screenshots. (And I am not including the time needed to process and compress the image before sending it).

Is there a way the get a better rate?
Maybe knowing which area of the screen changed before taking a screenshot?
Or should I just drop C# and go native?

Comment: Try it out in C++ and see if it makes a difference. Just grabbing the entire screen in a tight loop shouldn't be too difficult to write and measure.

Comment: Use Direct-X OR GDI and bitblt instead of GDI+. IF you use Direct-X, you can make it draw directly to a texture that you can send across the socket instead.. Maybe you can make it draw to a buffer as well.

Comment: Would you know where I can find more information on what you said about Direct-X? (I am using SlimDX and .Net 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mirror Driver, just google it, 'Demoforge Mirror Driver for TightVNC' will do the trick, but there are some others as well

Comment: Mirror driver technology is not working on Windows 8.
They replaced it with GDI...

Comment: The answer of the question 'Is there a way the get a better rate? Maybe knowing which area of the screen changed before taking a screenshot?' is mirror driver, and in UltraVNC forums, someone claims that they can use mirror driver in Windows 8, here is the topic : http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29855